# Reflect changes made to database on datagridview

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, refresh, edit

Guys I have two `DataGridView`s: `grid_display` and `grid_detail`.
`grid_detail` has a row from `grid_display`.

I am editing the row and saving the changes to database.
I now want THIS change to reflect in the `grid_display`.

Till now I have tried the `grid_display.Refresh();` with no apparent result.

Help please.

Comment: `grid_detail` has a row from `grid_display`? How are you populating data? Do you need to save to database from `grid_detail` or only from `grid_display`?

Comment: It means, @ColinSteel,I selected a row from grid_display and displayed ONLY that row in grid_detail. Need to save from grid_detail only.

Comment: I would update the `grid_display` with the values that you have changed in `grid_detail`, then save to the database from `grid_display`. Have you already tried this/decided against it?

Comment: Far simpler... You can use a `DataTable` as the `DataSource` for the `DataGridView`, filter to the columns that you want to display. And then call a couple of methods to update the database with changes for you automatically. I can post a full code sample and explanation for you later.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
grid_display.ResetBindings();
```

According to MSDN-

> This method causes a control bound to the BindingSource to reread all
>   the items in the list and refresh their displayed values.

Comment: No results @Microsoft DN :(

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings.aspx

Comment: Try grid_display.ResetBindings(false); OR grid_display.ResetBindings(true);

Answer (score 0):

First, if you editing row in datagridview, when you finished whit it, you must to cancel editing. For example you, editing row in grid_detail datagridview, you must to close editing. This is an example how to do it:

```
 grid_detail.EndEdit();
 ((DataRowView)grid_detail.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).EndEdit();
```

Now you can update the database with command:

```
yourtableadapter.Update(yourdataset.YourTable);
```

Then you can fill the second datagridview with modified or added (or deleted :) ) rows:

```
yourtavbleadapter.Fill(yourdataset.YourTable);
```

Hope, this helps to You .